# Regarding an usage of Chain of Responsibility

Tags: design-patterns

In the book Design Patterns : Elements of reusable object oriented software it is mentioned that Chain of Responsibility pattern can be used to let components access global properties through their parents. Can someone please enlighten me on this usage of the pattern?

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: Ketan...This is a doubt I came up with while reading and trying to understand the various design patterns in GOF-Design Patterns. So it is not specific to any problem for me to add details.

Answer (score 0):

The [Chain of Responsibility](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/ChainOfResponsibility/) allows an object to send a command without knowing which object will receive and handle it. The request is sent from one object to another making them parts of a chain and each object in this chain can handle the command, pass it on or do both.

Comment: Thanks dstar..the definition and working of COR is pretty clear to me. My question pertains to how this pattern is used by components to gain access to global properties via their parents.

Comment: is usage of the CoR in relation with Composite pattern ?